# symfony2 not redirecting properly after login_check

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, https, routes

I created a route named **dashboard**. 
The user will login first in the */dashboard/logout* route before accessing
the */dashboard/mailer* route.

The problem is the */dashboard/mailer* redirects to the */dashboard/login* again. See the images below.

[image]
[image]

You will notice that when it reaches the mailer route, it will send a Location header again pointing to the login route.

It works on my dev server without https but when I upload it to production with https, It does not redirect properly.

Here is my security.yml

[image]

Here is the *default_security_target*

[image]

In case you need it, [here is the .htaccess](http://pastebin.com/ukBPrzQD) in my production server. My production server is behind a load balancer with 2 nodes. The trusted_proxy configuration is also already set. Also, the firewall uses an in memory provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the sessions are not being managed correctly in the load balancers. When I login in the 1st server, the 2nd server will not see me authenticated thus being redirected to the login page.